# Javascript Detect Overflow with Padding Aware

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm making a Navbar that can transform between desktop & mobile version based on the screen width.

Unlike as Bootstrap's Navbar that utilizes `@media (min-width: ${minWidth}px)` for switching,
I am using a JavaScript for **overflowing detection**, by comparing `$0.clientWidth` & `$0.scrollWidth`.

The problem is, the `paddingRight` doesn't substract the `$0.clientWidth`, so the detection is inaccurate.

I want to get **the actual client width without padding** as shown by Chrome's page inspector.
As marked by the green rectangle on this illustration:
[image]

Note:

- I cannot apply a hack by adding `::after` for filling the right side,
  because the container is a grid, thus causing the ugly column gap.
- I cannot apply marginRight to the menu because the margin will fill the gridArea.

**Here the mockup of my Navbar.**
Please focus on the .js file:
[See & edit my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-with-overflowed-detection-du0wc?file=/src/index.js)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using list, i mean if your structure is like as

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <a href="#">
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then give the `padding` to the anchor tag, and then get the width of the `li` tag, your problem will be resolve

Comment: I'm using grid for the main container. Inside it there are logo, menu, & toggler. The menu is made from `<ul><li>` but it doesn't matter, because the javascript detect the main container (display: grid) for overflowing.

Comment: Do you want to detect the width of container ?

Comment: I've updated the post, visit my sandbox

Comment: I am adding another ans of your question

Comment: the main problem is `const overflowed = navbar.scrollWidth > navbar.clientWidth`. I'm struggling to **detect the real overflow**. Before going to `.mobile`, you can see the paddingRight is corrupted, it should be 80px, if corrupted => (overflowed === true). The detection is too late.

Comment: You give the `min-width` to `.main`, thats why padding is not applying on container, you should change `min-width` to `max-width` when mobile screen will appear

Comment: the `.main` of course always fill the document width (browser width). If one/more children get overflowed, then the main will be added some class to change the layout design. The Chrome's page inspector can draw the correct child area. How the calculation is performed?

Answer (score 0):

basically you want the actual width of the element without padding, you can achieve this by using javascript

```
 <script>
    function getWidth() {

        var elemWidth = 
            document.getElementById("navbar").offsetWidth;
        alert(elemWidth);
    }
</script>
```

inshort the trick is `offsetWidth` to get the elements inner-width.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code please check

> javascript

```
console.log('loaded')
const navbar = document.querySelector("#navbar");
const indicator = document.querySelector("#indicator");
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');


new ResizeObserver(() => {
  const overflowed = navbar.scrollWidth > navbar.clientWidth;

  if (overflowed) {
    indicator.classList.add('mobile');
    indicator.classList.remove('desktop');
    indicator.value = "overflowed => switch to mobile version";
    menu.classList.add('mobile');
  }
  else {
    indicator.classList.add('desktop');
    indicator.classList.remove('mobile');
    indicator.value = "not overflowed => desktop version";
    menu.classList.remove('mobile');
  }
})
.observe(navbar, { box: 'border-box' });
```

> Css

```
 body {
  margin: 20px;
}

.navbar {
  padding-inline: 80px;
  padding-block: 10px;
  background: #186EFB;
  border: solid 3px darkblue;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo   menu";
  column-gap: 10px;

  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  border: solid 3px darkred;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  align-self: stretch;
  justify-self: stretch;
  display: block;
  background: #14924C;
  border: solid 3px darkgreen;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

#indicator.desktop {
  background: lightgreen;
}
#indicator.mobile {
  background: pink;
}

.menu.mobile{
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: auto;
}
```